# Counting the number of rows of a program then working with them not working together

Tags: c, file

I wrote a code that first counts all the rows of a file, then I want it to re-check the rows for word filters and get info out of them. If I have both functions at once, the first function (counting the rows) blocks the second one (filtering for stuff).

Both of the functions work (counting all the rows and printing out the IP/Port), but only if one of them is deleted.

I think that the second while, that starts the filtering, wants to start at the bottom of the file and doesn't find anything and just stops.

```
char getIP(const char source[300], char result[300])
{
    int cnt;
    const char *readIn;
    readIn = strstr(source, "172");

    for(cnt = 0; readIn[cnt] != ':'; cnt++)
        result[cnt] = readIn[cnt];
    result[cnt] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

char getPort(const char source[300], char result[300])
{
    int cnt;
    const char *readIn;
    readIn = strchr(source, ':');

    for(cnt = 0; readIn[cnt] != ' '; cnt++)
        result[cnt] = readIn[cnt];
    result[cnt] = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("Netstat.txt", "r+");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Netstat.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    char row[300], IP[30], Port[10];
    char *temp;
    int row_cnt = 0, readytostart = 0, cnt;
    while(fgets(row, 300, file) != NULL)
        row_cnt++;
    printf("Number of Rows: %d\n", row_cnt);

    while(fgets(row, 300, file) != NULL)
    {
        temp = row;
        if(temp[0] == '#' && temp[1] == '#' && temp[2] == '#')
            readytostart = 1;
        if(readytostart > 0)
        {
            if(strstr(row, "HERGESTELLT") != NULL && strstr(row, "127.0.0.1") == NULL)
            {
              getIP(row, IP); getPort(row, Port);
              printf("IP Adresse: %s  Port: %s\n", IP, Port);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I want my code to count all the rows first, so I get a number at the end, then look through all the rows again that has the word "HERGESTELLT" but not the IP Address of 127.0.0.1. If that's the case, the IP address and Port should be copied into new arrays and then printed out with printf.

Comment: Forgot the Netstat.txt: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J6IdaSOCLwKXOepBMAf0aPjjk15DIN_q)

Comment: Please indent your code consistently

Comment: What do you mean? This is the whole code

Comment: Call `rewind(file);` to reset the file position back to the start of the file before the second pass.